# Jquery animate div opacity on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, opacity

So I'm trying to animate a css property based on scrolling the browser window.
the code below works so far, but I'd like it to have a transition instead of just abruptly snapping from an opacity of 1 to an opacity of 0.5. any help is appreciated.  thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
        $('.header').css('background','rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5)');
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50){
        $('.header').css('background','rgba(200, 54, 54, 1)');
    }
});
```

});

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/XXjZW/) link to the code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
        $('.header').css('background','rgb(200, 54, 54)').stop().animate({"opacity":".5"},1000)
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50){
        $('.header').css('background','rgb(200, 54, 54)').stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},1000)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXjZW/2/

Comment: Thanks.  this code and the following example work great, but it brings me to another question.  How can i animate the background opacity with affecting the h1 tag inside the header div?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 property `transition`:

```
.header{
    -webkit-transition:background 1s;
    -moz-transition:background 1s;
    -o-transition:background 1s;
    transition:background 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give your css transition ->

```
transition:background 1s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXjZW/6/

Answer (score 1):

If you want compatibility with browsers which don't suppor CSS3, I would recommend you to make use of jQuery UI library:

```
  $('.header').animate({
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000"
  }, 1000);
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/XXjZW/8/

You will need to include it as you include jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```